# TFS 2017 with Update 1 exponential database growth

Tags: azure-devops

In the last days we have seen an exponential growth in our on-premise TFS installation. The table that is growing is tbl_Content and we have narrow the kind of files to git pack files.

The problem for tracking what is happening is that we have't yet figure out how to link an entry in that table with a commit id, a repository, pull request or something that would point us in the the right direction.

Can anyone please share how can we link an entry in that table with what is creating it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try the ways in this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe992926-dd58-488e-9fd1-9862a5f6ebe8/tfs-2017-u1-dbotblcontent-growing-dramatically-rowssize?forum=tfsversioncontrol

Comment: Another thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/63712/tfs-database-size.html

Comment: What's the result after trying with these ways?

Comment: Using the repack procedure we were able to release a lot of space and control the growth. In the past someone on the team added a binary file to the git repository and later that commit was removed from git. When we created a repository mirror the size was much smaller then what it was using on the database and we think that somehow TFS was not dealing well with this deleted commit and that might have caused the problem. Anyway the repack procedure fixed the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is using repack procedure.

Some related threads:

[TFS Database size](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/63712/tfs-database-size.html)

[TFS 2017 u1 dbo.tbl_content growing dramatically (rows+size)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe992926-dd58-488e-9fd1-9862a5f6ebe8/tfs-2017-u1-dbotblcontent-growing-dramatically-rowssize?forum=tfsversioncontrol)